# How do I resolve a Javascript template literal variable within a string within a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, templates, chatbot, literals

I'm using node.js and experimenting with building a chatbot.

One of my replies is `hello ${username}` which is being returned in a string from a database query.

`msg.channel.send(results.rows[index].reply);`

But that just sends `hello ${username}` when I would like `${username}` to resolve to a local variable containing the user's name. e.g. hello Mark.

Is it possible?

Thanks for the replies. I settled on:

```
let reply = results.rows[index].reply;
reply = reply.replace('${username}', username);

msg.channel.send(reply);
```

I should have said that I did try:

```
msg.channel.send(`${results.rows[index].reply}`);
```

hoping that it would be resolved recursively, but it wasn't.

Comment: No easy way to do this using Javascript template literals. This is not what Javascript template literals were designed for. They use the word "literal" in their name for a reason because they are designed to do substitutions in string literals where the string is known at parse/compile time, not where the string comes programmatically from elsewhere (such as from your database) in a variable. Other sources I read when researching this suggested using a Javascript template engine such as EJS, PUG, HBS, etc... since this is what they were designed for.

Comment: The answers you are getting are all attempting to design your own template expansion engine.  Rather than build your own, I'd suggest you just use one of the many pre-built engines that are already out there that all have well documented formats and lots of extensibility.  To name a few: EJS, PUG, HBS, NUNJUCKS, etc...  They are commonly used for generating dynamic HTML, but can be used just fine for things like this too.

Answer (score 2):

You can replace all occurrences of already declared `strings`, You can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here and declare strings that you are going to replace with.

The below code also handles the case where you didn't declare the replacement string in the map and returns the original string as it is.

```js
const query =
  "hello ${username}, your email id is ${useremail} and password is ${userpassword}";
const map = new Map();
map.set("username", "Mark");
map.set("useremail", "mark@email.com");

const result = query.replace(/\$\{(.*?)\}/g, (...match) => {
  return map.has(match[1]) ? map.get(match[1]) : `${match[0]}`;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: you can also use an object instead of Map and change the replacer function with `return map[match[1]] ?? match[0]`

Answer (score 1):

If you know in advance the variables you expect you can do this:

```
const username = 'John Smith';
const strFromDB = 'hello ${username}.';
const strWithUser = strFromDB.replace('${username}', username);
```

Comment: This simplified template structure requires knowing in advance what might be in the template string and doing a replace for each possible value and does not support arbitrary variable references.  This is not really in the spirit of what was being asked (Javascript template literal-type functionality).  Of course, one can always build your own template expansion engine.  I don't think that's what was being asked.